# Multiply numpy array by large numpy packedbit array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, bitarray

I have a very large binary array which I compress using

```
arr1 = np.random.randint(0,2,(100, 100))
bitArray = np.packbits(arr1)
```

How can I then multiply another numpy integer array by this packed array,

```
arr2 = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100))
result = MULTIPLY(arr2,bitArray)
```

treating the values as standard ones and zeros such that the result would be the same as

```
np.dot(arr2,arr1)
```

without ever converting the bitarray out of the packed format?

Comment: why do you think this is possible?  Fast `dot` is implemented in C code expecting standard floats and doubles.  I doubt if even simple element wise multiplication is possible, e.g. `3*bitArray`.

Comment: Have you looked at the values of the samples?  Why all 0s?

Comment: 0's was a typo. I mean definitionally it *should* be possible. Question of whether I have to somehow implement my own BLAS routines or if I can use Numpy.